# How To Assign the value in OneModel to AnotherModel

Tags: c#

How to Assign the value in one model to another model without using AutoMapper ,foreach,and instance and then it will access any way to send value in one model to another model its is possible and then my source model will be byte array ..

This is my source model...

```
public class OneDriveItem : OneDriveItemBase
{             
    public string Id { get; set; }            
    public string Name { get; set; }            
    public string ETag { get; set; }        
    public OneDriveIdentitySet CreatedBy { get; set; }       
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public OneDriveIdentitySet LastModifiedBy { get; set; }  
    public DateTimeOffset LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public string WebUrl { get; set; }
    public OneDriveItem[] Children { get; set; }
    public OneDriveRemoteItem RemoteItem{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my Target Model

```
public  class OneDriveModels
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Etag { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WebUrl { get; set; }
    public string CTag { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string DownloadUrlAnnotation { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you please update the question, adding in more detail about what your source and target applications are, and why you want to avoid `foreach` - a language construct?  As is, I think this will end up getting closed because there's not enough information about what your're trying to do, or any evidence of what you've already tried...

Comment: As an aside, would some form of JSON serialization work here?  Pretty sure you can configure something to ignore properties that aren't in the target model.

Comment: I was already serialization the json string, but I have some issues of DateTimeOffset to byte[] conversion how can I fix this problem.

Comment: `I have some issues of DateTimeOffset to byte[]` what issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can decide not to look for a shortcut and do it with a constructor/factory method.

For example:

```
public  class OneDriveModels
{
   public static FromOneDriveItem( OneDriveItem source)  
   {
       Id = source.Id
       ETag = source.ETag
       (...)
   }
```